# Redirect from Node Js to Spring boot service and send back responce

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, express, redirect

I have one angular UI running on localhost:4200, node server running on localhost:4000 and one spring boot service running on localhost:8080.

I want to make flow from angualr to node and from node to redirect to spring boot service which is having web UI where user give confirmation and respone will be give to node and for node to angualr.

Issue is spring boot service is not only REST service. user will give input on web ui. So how to redirect to UI of spring service with keeping track of node and angular.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are two different sites involved, you can not simply do a backend to backend API call and redirect once. You will most probably have to do the following -

1. The user navigates to the first webapp *(say webapp1)* which is running behind a **NodeJs** server and then possibly the user makes some API call to Node.
2. Once the NodeJs server processes the request, it will send a redirect response back to *webapp1* which the browser will then redirect the user to *webapp2*. (You probably might need to add a query parameter such as token to validate the redirected user with the second app)

So the redirect response should look like

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://webapp2.com/?token=12345
```

3. This should load the second webapp which talks to the **Spring** service. Now when the processing of that is done, you will need to do the same as step2 to return the user back to *webapp1*.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://webapp1.com/?token=12345
```

[image]

Comment: thanx for this good clarificaion. But here the question is how to redirect to spring from may be UI and from spring to node.

Comment: @sam glad to help you. If you think this would solve the issue, please accept it as an answer.